# how to use map in Go

Tags: loops, go, range, maps

I want to make a simple program to count debt installments. The requirements are:

1. Input the debt value
2. Input how long the installments
3. The first half of the installment bank interest is 11% and the rest are 8%
4. Must use maps

Here's my code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    fmt.Print("Input the debt value : ")
    var debt int
    fmt.Scanln(&debt)

    fmt.Print("Input how long the installments : ")
    var installment int
    fmt.Scanln(&installment)

    fmt.Println("====================================================")
    fmt.Println("Total debt : ", debt)
    fmt.Println("Installments : ", installment)
    fmt.Println("====================================================")
    var firstHalf = installment / 2

    var pay int
    for i := 1; i <= installment; i++ {

        value := map[string]int{
            "month":    i,
            "payment": pay,
        }

        if i <= firstHalf {
            pay = (debt / installment) + (debt * 11 / 100)
            fmt.Println(value["month"],"Installment with bank interest (11%) is", value["payment"])
        } else {
            pay = (debt / installment) + (debt * 8 / 100)
            fmt.Println(value["month"],"Installment with bank interest (8%) is", value["payment"])
        }
    }

}
```

If I run the code and for example :

The debt is 10.000.000
The installments are 7 months

Here's the output :

```
1 Installment with bank interest (11%) is 0
2 Installment with bank interest (11%) is 2528571
3 Installment with bank interest (11%) is 2528571
4 Installment with bank interest (8%) is 2528571
5 Installment with bank interest (8%) is 2228571
6 Installment with bank interest (8%) is 2228571
7 Installment with bank interest (8%) is 2228571
```

I don't know why the first index is always 0, even the next calculation is right. So, I guess that either I am using the wrong syntax or I am trying to do something that can not be done. Maybe most likely experienced people will see right away what is wrong.

Comment: You initialize `pay`, print the map, and then next time around put that `pay` into the map.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/wWVyQMgADY4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing the the `payment` value of map as 0 because it is assigned with `pay` which has no value initially.You can fix this by declaring the map beneath the if else condition and then print your values,here is the modified code for the same logic:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    fmt.Print("Input the debt value : ")
    var debt int
    fmt.Scanln(&debt)

    fmt.Print("Input how long the installments : ")
    var installment int
    fmt.Scanln(&installment)

    fmt.Println("====================================================")
    fmt.Println("Total debt : ", debt)
    fmt.Println("Installments : ", installment)
    fmt.Println("====================================================")
    var firstHalf = installment / 2

    var pay int
    for i := 1; i <= installment; i++ {

        if i <= firstHalf {
            pay = (debt / installment) + (debt * 11 / 100)

        } else {
            pay = (debt / installment) + (debt * 8 / 100)

        }
        value := map[string]int{
            "month":   i,
            "payment": pay,
        }

        if i <= firstHalf {

            fmt.Println(value["month"], "Installment with bank interest (11%) is", value["payment"])
        } else {

            fmt.Println(value["month"], "Installment with bank interest (8%) is", value["payment"])
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Input the debt value : 1000
Input how long the installments : 5
====================================================
Total debt :  1000
Installments :  5
====================================================
1 Installment with bank interest (11%) is 310
2 Installment with bank interest (11%) is 310
3 Installment with bank interest (8%) is 280
4 Installment with bank interest (8%) is 280
5 Installment with bank interest (8%) is 280
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if i <= firstHalf {
   pay = (debt / installment) + (debt * 11 / 100)
   value["payment"] = pay
   fmt.Println(value["month"],"Installment with bank interest (11%) is", 
   value["payment"])
} else {
     pay = (debt / installment) + (debt * 8 / 100)
     value["payment"] = pay
     fmt.Println(value["month"],"Installment with bank interest (8%) is", 
     value["payment"])
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.